# flag |= f == s[i], what will this statement do?

Tags: c++

`flag |= f == s[i]`, what this statement will do, where `flag==0`, `f` is a `string` and `s` is the array of strings.

```
int main()
{
    int n; 
    cin >> n; 

    vector<string> s(n); 
    vector<int> t(n); 

    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) 
    { 
        cin >> s[i] >> t[i];
    }

    string f; 
    cin >> f; 

    int ans = 0; 
    int flag = 0; 

    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) 
    { 
        ans += flag * t[i]; 
        flag |= f == s[i]; 
    } 

    cout << ans << '\n'; 
    return 0; 
}
```

Comment: *"I found this statement someone else code"* Ask to that *someone else*

Comment: Did you try running it and seeing what it does? Also, when you found someone else's code, was it also an entire program on a single line?

Comment: Do you understand `flag = flag | (f == s[i])` better? If flag was true it stays true. If flag was false and `f == s[i]` is true it becomes true.

Answer (score 2):

`flag |= f == s[i]` can be written `flag = flag | f == s[i]` is a **bitwise OR** between the value of `flag` and the result of `f == s[i]` (0 or 1).

This will set `flag` to 1 if at any time `f == s[i]`

```
flag | f == s[i] | result
-----+-----------+-------
 0   | 0         | 0
 0   | 1         | 1
 1   | 0         | 1
 1   | 1         | 1
```

In *this case*, this is a shorthand for

```
if (f == s[i])
{
    flag = 1;
}
```

Comment: @sp2danny in *this case* it is right. since `flag` will only get the value `0` or `1`. However, I edited the answer to make sure it won't confuse futur readers

Answer (score 1):

First of all, compound assignment (like `|=`) is equal to e.g.

```
flag = flag | f == s[i]
```

Then comparison using `==` results in a `bool` value (either `true` or `false`).

The type `bool` can be implicitly converted to an `int`, with `false` being `0` and `true` being `1`.

So what this does is either

```
flag = flag | 0;  // f == s[i] is false
```

or

```
flag = flag | 1;  // f == s[i] is true
```

Lastly the `|` operator which is the [*bitwise or*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bitwise_operation#OR). Bitwise or with `1` will set the lowest bit. If `flag` is `0` then it will either stay `0` (if `f == s[i]` is false) or it will become `1` (if `f == s[i]` is true). Once set to `1` the value of `flag` will not change value again in the shown code.

Answer (score 0):

Flag being 0 at the start "neutralizes" the

```
ans += flag * t[i]; //ans += 0* t[i] <==> ans = ans + 0 <==> {;}
```

Once flag turns true at `flag |= f == s[i];` (when `f == s[i]`), it stays true (because `true|false==true` and `true|true==true`, and the operation becomes

```
ans += 1 * t[i]; // <==> ans += t[i];
```

Instead of `ans += flag * t[i];`, you could have `if (flag) ans += t[i];`.

Alternatively, you could use a function (or goto) instead of the flag:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

int sum_since(std::vector<int> const &X, size_t N)
{
    size_t top = X.size();
    int r=0; for(size_t i=N; i<top; i++) r+=X[i];
    return r;
}

int main() { 
    int n; 
    cin >> n; 
    vector<string> s(n); 
    vector<int> t(n); 
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) { 
        cin >> s[i] >> t[i]; 
    } 
    string f; 
    cin >> f; 
    int ans = 0; 
    int flag = 0; 
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
        if( f==s[i] ) { ans=sum_since(t,i); break; }
    cout << ans << '\n'; 
    return 0; 
}
```